# Sea-Going Ground-Effect Vehicle

Tags: commercial-aviation, efficiency, seaplane, ekranoplan

Is a [Ground-effect vehicle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground-effect_vehicle) (a.k.a. ekranoplan) practical in seas near the coast (e.g. the US East Coast, West Coast, and Gulf of Mexico)?

I'm looking for a practicality answer, like, nope, cannot be done, yes, it can, or, we don't really know yet.

Comment: Problem is you have all these vehicles flying around at high speed at the same altitude.  If it got busy enough you'd eventually get them running into each other.

Comment: This is being done right now (article from April 2022): *"A prototype sea-to-air passenger craft has clocked more than 35 knots (70kph) in sea trials off Tampa, Florida this month - and a New Zealand company is today announcing the $700 million purchase of some of the first commercial production models."* https://www.newsroom.co.nz/nz-investors-order-25-foiling-electric-gliders-for-high-speed-coastal-commuting

Comment: can you define what you mean by "practical"?

Comment: As far as I know no ground-effect vehicle has ever operated regularly on the open ocean.

Comment: @Federico: Sure, practical = can capture most of the benefits of travel in a lake environment or Caspian Sea (like ekratoplan), but in an ocean environment near the coast.

Comment: 70kph...is slower than a very fast cyclist.